# Flash CS6 Generate Sprite Sheet zeros issue

Tags: flash-cs6, sprite-sheet, starling-framework

When in Flash CS6 i want to generate sprite sheet , it works fine , creates one big texture and XML file. But! Even if my movieclip has only one frame , in XML it appears like "Cosmonaut0000" , it is his library name and extra four zeros . These zeros are very unnecessary . I work with Starling framework and these zeros causing me to write like this: `AssetsManager.getAtlas().getTexture(("star0000"))`. 
Question: may be somewhere in Flash preferences there is an option to shut those zeros down?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ya zeros will come when we create spritesheet through CS6. Just Replace with these zeros with null using select that zeros which you not require. Ctrl+F and replace with null so that all those zeros will be removed.

Comment: you mean remove them in xml file? but all the time i'll recreate this xml file when i publish the spritesheet , zeros come again

Comment: Ya , you can't ignore 00 while we creating spritesheet. Its Obvious its an convertion problem from movieclip to bitmap texture.